# What is the expected probability of error of a channel?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{X} , P, \mathcal{Y})$ be a channel with $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y} = \{0,1\}$ and transition matrix
>
> $$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
> 7/8 &1/8 \\
> 1/8 &7/8 
> \end{bmatrix}.$$
>
> The input probabilities are $P[X = 0] = 0.3, P[X = 1] = 0.7$. Each input bit is encoded by
>   transmitting it through the channel $2n + 1$ times, and the decoding function is the majority
>   bit (the bit $0$ or $1$ that appears more times in the sequence of $2n + 1$ output bits).
>   Let $f(n)$ be the expected probability of error, that is, the probability that the decoded bit is
>   different from the encoded bit.
>
> Express $f(n)$ as a sum of the form $f(n) = \sum_{k=\ldots}^\ldots (\ldots)$.

I do not know what is meant with the "expected probability of error", we did not define this in the lecture. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: I think it just means "probability of error."  By symmetry, the probability of error given $X=0$ is the same as the probability of error given $X=1$.  And any sum expression for $f(n)$ should be of the form $f(n) = \sum_{i=...}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this solved my question.